# How to call a printer with OPOS in Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, printing, opos

I am trying to develop a POS for Windows 8. 
Unfortunately I have no experiences with handling external devices like POS-printers, displays , scanners etc.

For this moment I only want to find a way, to print my bills on a POS-printer. 
After some research I found out, that there is a driver standard called OPOS. If I understand that right, than every POS-printer which comes with a OPOS-driver can be called in my application. Is that right?

And: if it is: where can I find an implementation for that (or an example) ?

I tried to use Microsoft's "POS for .NET" - but that is very old stuff and does not work in Windows 8 apps. 
Can you please give me some tipps and tricks?

Comment: POS .NET 1.14 was released in 2014 and it supports Windows 8.1 though not sure about Windows 10 [POS for .NET FAQ (POS for .NET v1.14 SDK Documentation)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee406171(v=winembedded.4).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.monroecs.com and download the latest Common Control Objects for OPOS (version 1.14 as of this writing.)  Then use COM Interop to access them from your .Net app.  Or write your code in C++ and interface directly with them.